# SQLite - Select From Temporary Table Issue(Ionic v3)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am trying to translate a long query written in T-SQL Into SQLite in Ionic. At first, I am trying to create temporary tables like the following:

```
 this.SQLObj.executeSql(`  

    CREATE TEMP TABLE Variables (Name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Value TEXT);
    INSERT INTO temp.Variables VALUES ('WorkingDays', '2222');
    Select * from temp.Variables;

    `,[]).then(res=>{

         console.log(res);

        }).catch(err=>{

         console.log(err);

          })
```

However, I am not getting any results.

```
insertId:undefined
rows:Object {item: , length: 0}
item:function(i) { … }
length:0
```

How can I use temporary tables or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: show us the ionic code you trying

Comment: I edited the question you can see the code